# How to read string from sqlite using sqlite3_prepare_v2()?

Tags: c++, sqlite

i have a sqlite3 database and i need to query on it using visual c++ 2013?
i am using sqlite3.h for creating connection an manipulate database;

i am using this code to retraive data :

```
   sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT * FROM response where list_id =?", -1, &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, *2*);
tree<SensorState>::iterator itr = sensorTree.begin(); 
for (;;)
{
    int rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (rc == SQLITE_DONE){
        break; 
    }
    else if (rc != SQLITE_ROW){
        cout << "error in reading sensore with error No: " << rc;
        break; 
    }
    const char* name = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)); 
    int value = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 3);
    cout << name<< "->" << value <<endl;  
}
```

now in terminal i am getting this outbut: 
[image]

but it must show this output:

```
s1->5
s2->2
s4->2
```

how can i rea string correctly from sqlite3 using c++?

Comment: it was a typo mistake i edit my question

Comment: The code looks fine; make sure that the data inside of the database is correct (ex. by opening the database with the command-line sqlite shell).

Comment: i see data using  SQlite browser a useful plugin for fire fox and every things  were prefect and no issue found in database

Comment: Show the table structure. BTW, using `SELECT *` is extremely dangerous because it will blow up whenever the table's columns change.

Comment: i check and debug my program and i found that my data witch come from  db are fine but it sounds when i print value it loss encoding .... i run my program multiple time an i got different result.... and all of them was wrong

Comment: Is the table structure so top secret that you cannot show it?